# Not able to bluebird.Promisifyall gm

Tags: bluebird, gm

The gm is giving the `gm().write() expects a callback function` error. The write function comes from `fs` so I also promisified it. Still it does not work.

```
var gm = bluebird.promisifyAll(require("gm"));
var fs = bluebird.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

gm(filePath).resize(null, 128).write(file)
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Done");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

How to use promise with `gm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluebird's normal scheme for promisifying with `promisifyAll()` creates `.writeAsync()` that returns a promise.  It doesn't change `.write()` at all.  This assumes that the object that `gm()` returns is something that Bluebird can get to via `gm.prototype`.

So, you'd do this:

```
const gm = require("gm");
bluebird.promisifyAll(gm.prototype);

gm(filePath).resize(null, 128).writeAsync(file).then(function() {
    console.log("Done");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note: You don't have to promisify the `fs` module unless you're going to use the fs promisified methods directly yourself.

Comment: I tried your solution but it is giving `gm(...).resize(...).writeAsync is not a function` error.

Comment: @SharadCodes - Then, maybe `gm()` is not directly compatible with Bluebird's `.promisifyAll()`.  I'm not familiar with that library specifically to know what it returns after `gm().resize()`.  Apparently whatever that object is is not getting promisified.

Comment: I tried `var gm = require("gm"); Promise.promisifyAll(gm.prototype);
` then it worked. Why it worked is completely over me.

Comment: @SharadCodes - What version of Bluebird are you running.  The [Bluebird doc I read here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html), says that `.promisfyAll()` already promisifies the prototype for you.

Comment: I am using version 3.4.3.